# Putting all the days info in one cell, in dynamic table in employee schedule

Tags: php, mysql, scheduled-tasks

I have a table with info from the each day:

```
idDya | date | startHour | endHour | totalHours | name
-------------------------------------------------------
1       05/01   12:00       16:00       4         John
2       05/01   12:00       16:00       4         Marko
3       05/02   12:00       17:00       3         John
4       05/02   12:00       17:00       3         Peter
5       05/03   12:50       18:00       5         Peter
```

and I have a dynamic table:

```
<?php

    $sql = " SELECT * FROM days "; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<table  width='435' border='1' cborder='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#666666' class='boldtable'>

    <tr>
    <td>".$row['idDya']."</td>
    <td>".$row['date ']."</td>
    <td>".$row['totalHours']."</td>
    <td>".$row['name']."</td>
    </tr>

    </table>";

    }
?>
```

Question: "How can I format a table, so I have a dynamic table, but that each cell fits combine information for that date".

```
day        schedule
--------------------------------

05/01 |     John    12:00 -16:00     
            Marko   12:00 -16:00

--------------------------------

05/02 |     John    12:00 -16:00     
            Peter   12:00 -16:00

--------------------------------

etc...
```

Comment: why would u store this in a table? this sounds like something that should be done application-side.

Comment: it looks like a table for tracking employee hours why wouldnt he keep that in a database?

Comment: Your query should be `SELECT * FROM DAYS ORDER BY Date, StartHour`. Then use logic in PHP to do a control break on the days. Note that if your `Date` column really is a string that says `05/01`, `05/02`, etc., this approach won't work - but then again you'll have plenty of other problems to deal with if the date is stored like that.

Comment: rowspan on first table cell?

Comment: Oh, I just put like a example of a date, its not the actual format. The format is 1111-11-11. I would agree with PlanTheldea that should be application side , php but still what what kind of format of dinamic table would be?

Comment: Hey Ed Gibbs, thanx for reply. Can you give me an example of such Php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it convenient to  use `GROUP_CONCAT()` on MySql side to pack and get details per day in one go to further `explode()` it on php side while rendering your page

```sql
SELECT date, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', name, startHour, endHour) ORDER BY name) schedule
  FROM days
 GROUP BY date
```

Sample output:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
| date       | schedule                                       |
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-05-01 | John|12:00:00|16:00:00,Marko|12:00:00|16:00:00 |
| 2013-05-02 | John|12:00:00|17:00:00,Peter|12:00:00|17:00:00 |
| 2013-05-03 | Peter|12:50:00|18:00:00                        |
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/549e5/1)** demo

---

Now here is how you can process it in php with PDO

```php
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$sql = "SELECT date, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', name, startHour, endHour) ORDER BY name) schedule
          FROM days
         GROUP BY date";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query = null;
$db = null;
?>

<table width='435' border='1' cborder='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#666666' class='boldtable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Schedule</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>
              <td>{$row['date']}</td><td>";
        $schedule = explode(',', $row['schedule']);
        foreach($schedule as $details) {
            list($name, $start_hour, $end_hour) = explode('|', $details);
            echo "$name $start_hour-$end_hour<br>";
        }
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
?>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sample output:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: @Iznogud Did it help? Do you need more help with your original question?

Comment: Hey Peter, sorry for the slow respond. This is exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly. Im still a newbie and what I learn from  your code here is on what way should I think to resolve the problem. Thanks a million!!!